# Is there an online database that maps functions with their signature?

Tags: solidity, abi

I have already seen a site with all the functions of solidity with its signature, but do not remember its url, I'm looking for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you mean the Ethereum Function Signature Database https://www.4byte.directory/. From the site:

> This database is meant to allow mapping those 4-byte signatures back to their human readable versions.

Answer (score 2):

(Working) alternative is: https://sig.eth.samczsun.com/ also take a look at https://tools.deth.net