# How to know bytes4 value of external method calling a contract

Tags: solidity

Is there anyway to know the name of the external method calling a contract's method from within the called contract method?

As an example, msg.sender gives you the address of the calling contract. I tried using msg.sig, however msg.sig gives you the function of the contract being called and not the name of the function where the original call came from.

In my particular application, I do not have control of the calling contract so I cant have a solution on that end.

Method A From Contract A calls Method B From Contract B.

Contract B needs to know what method from Contract A Called without Contract A passing that information.

Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an online database that maps functions with their signature?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/31828/is-there-an-online-database-that-maps-functions-with-their-signature)

Comment: Hi tayray! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! The answer in this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/102816/is-there-anyway-to-know-the-name-of-the-external-method-calling-a-contract is correct: The EVM doesn't provide the information needed about the calling contract, only the caller address.